# Invalid Session ID error appearing randomly

Tags: api, session, php

I am using the PHP partner API for salesforce and am coming across a rather odd issue randomly. Here is the error message I am getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID] INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key:

I have done some research and a lot of people are saying to make sure that the "Lock sessions to originating IP Address" checkbox is NOT checked. I made sure of that and it's still happening. I should mention that the server that we have noticed it on is a load balanced server, but the IP's don't change. Any ideas what could be causing this? I can not recreate the issue, but have received several emails from clients with the same error message. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Wondering if it could be to do with a stale session?

Comment: I was thinking that too, but it seems to happen the first time they hit the page that has uses the API, so the session ID doesn't appear to be set yet. As far as I can tell at least.